# docker-compose cannot find the yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I've placed a docker compose file **project.yaml** at the location /etc/project/project.yaml

the file and well as the project directory have the same file permission, i.e. -rxwrxxrwx
but when I run docker-compose

```
sudo docker-compose -f ./project.yaml up -d
```

if errors out with the following
Cannot find the file ./project.yaml

I have checked various times and it seems there is no permission issue. Can anyone tell why we have this problem and what would be the solution

Comment: you can try `sudo docker-compose -f /etc/project/project.yaml up -d`

Answer (score 3):

Beside using the full path, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73500671/docker-compose-cannot-find-the-yaml-file#comment129801726_73500671) by [quoc9x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14312225/quoc9x), double-check your current working directory when you call a command with a relative path `./project.yaml`

If you are not in the right folder, that would explain the error message.